# Installed LAMP server and php myadmin, no .my.cnf file

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-10.04, lamp

I just installed apache LAMP server along with phpmyadmin to make database editing easier. Now that I've installed everything, I can't find the .my.cnf file that should have been generated. I thought it would be in my home directory but it isn't.

Comment: What Linux distro are you using and how did you install phpmyadmin and MySQL?

Comment: As tagged, I'm using ubuntu 10.04. I installed MySQL as part of the LAMP stack package. I installed phpmyadmin seperately under the mysql server through the ubuntu package manager. I hope my responses made sense. I'm new at server systems and not yet exactly what you would call competent.

Comment: Why do you expect there to have been a .my.cnf file generated?

Comment: @andol Because the only other times that I've used a mysql database on a LAMP server there was one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The my.cnf is in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` unless you installed it from the repository. If it is (for whatever reason) not in this place issue an `sudo find / -iname my.cnf` and see where it is.

Comment: I did install from the repository, and yes, it's there. Thanks!